Identifying vise mounting flange component
Shown below is one style of vise assembly, where a lead screw with a special grooved end fits into a slotted mounting flange.

I'm having trouble finding these slotted mounting flanges online in various sizes - does anyone know if they're commercially available? There's one listing here without clear specifications shipping from Europe.
If these flanges are as hard to come by as it seems, what other similar mounting hardware might work? Perhaps a mount using a section of T-slot? Something involving retaining rings? At the end of the day I need to mount the end of a grooved end lead screw so that the screw is free to rotate, but cannot move axially at the end, as is common in certain bench vises.
Thanks for the help!

"I'm having trouble finding these slotted mounting flanges online" Not surprised as I think they're very specific to this application. There are various workarounds though, the simplest being simply to modify a heavy washer (drill, hacksaw, files) then mount it in the required location with a hole bored in the wood behind to accommodate as much of the lead screw as needed. These washers (called simply horseshoe washers commercially I think) are available as spares for vices from certain manufacturers, but I think are hardly needed given the simplicity of fabricating similar for mere pennies.
